# Append div to end of document with jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

I would like to write a function using jQuery to append a `div` to the end of a web page.  I would like to be able to use the function on many different pages.

I've written the following code, but it doesn't work:

```
    $(document).append('<div id="helloDiv"></div>');
    $('#helloDiv').html('hello'); // does nothing
    $('#helloDiv').css('top','100') // throws an error
```

How do I fix this?

Comment: I think it's because you're appending it directly to the document. Try appending it to $('body')

Comment: Thanks guys!  This site saves me so much time and frustration!

Comment: For JS, see: [How to add content to html body using JS?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13495010/55075)

Answer (score 50, accepted):

It is meaningless to append to the `document`.  Append to the document's `body` node instead, since this is where all the visible content is:

```
$(document.body).append('<div id="helloDiv"></div>');
```

Answer (score 9):

If you want it to be at the end of the `body`, why not use:

```
$('body').append('<div id="helloDiv"></div>');
$('#helloDiv').html('hello');
$('#helloDiv').css('top', 100);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ptuxX/

However, just `.css('top', 100)` does not do much unless you set the `position` to `absolute`.

Comment: and it should be .css('top', 100) without quotes or .css('top', '100px')

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
$('body').append('<div id="helloDiv"></div>');
$('#helloDiv').html('hello');
$('#helloDiv').css('top', '100');
```

Or just add the content and it's css before adding the div.

```
var $newdiv = '<div id="helloDiv">hello</div>';
$('body').append($newdiv);
```