# How to add content to html body using JS?

Tags: javascript

I have many `<section>` in my html `<body>` and want to add more through javascript. However, using `innerHTML` is just replacing my existing sections with new ones, instead of adding them to the old ones.

What else can I use?

Comment: If you provide your code so far, you'll get a more specific answer.

Answer (score 67, accepted):

You can use

```
document.getElementById("parentID").appendChild(/*..your content created using DOM methods..*/)
```

or

```
document.getElementById("parentID").innerHTML+= "new content"
```

Comment: I'd always go for DOM methods where possible; [`.createElement`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/document.createElement), [`.appendChild`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/Node.appendChild), [`.insertBefore`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/Node.insertBefore), [`.replaceChild`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/Node.replaceChild), etc.

Comment: I know this is an old answer, but += on innerHTML is a not a good way of appending content to an element. I did the += on an element that had ads loaded already and the ads actually just went blank after appending content. Switching to appendChild(element) vs += "content" fixed the ad disappearing issue. Just an FYI for future users who landed on this page from Google :)

Comment: 2nd brakes modern JS apps and many other things, especially ones working with "virtual" DOM aka ReactJs and similar. Use appendChild always. 2nd option will take current value, append your new string, and replace the current value, which terminates connection between virtual dom state and dom rendered on screen. stuff will brake. use use 1st. `appendChild` or other DOM api.

Answer (score 30):

I Just came across to a similar to this question solution with included some performance statistics.

It seems that example below is faster:

```js
document.getElementById('container').insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', '<div id="idChild"> content html </div>');
```

InnerHTML vs jQuery 1 vs appendChild vs innerAdjecentHTML.

[image]

Reference: 
1) [Performance stats](https://jsperf.com/insert-html-to-div)
2) [API - insertAdjacentHTML](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/insertAdjacentHTML)

I hope this will help.

Comment: Thanks! insertAdjacentHTML method is quite helpful!

Comment: Also good to mention that it works on most of the browsers including Internet Explorer 4+

Answer (score 27):

I think if you want to add content directly to the body, the best way is:

```
document.body.innerHTML += "bla bla";
```

To replace it, use:

```
document.body.innerHTML = "bla bla";
```

Comment: To append instead of erase >>

    document.body.innerHTML += "bla bla";

Comment: This answer is misleading, because the first way (`document.body.innerHTML = "bla blah";`) is not adding content to the body, it's ***replacing*** the content in the body. And the user specifically asked for a way to add content to a body that already has existing content. So the answer to the question is what you're showing as technique #2. Technique #1 you could add as a side note with explanation.

Comment: this has side effects on JS apps and this approach brakes events and all kind of random things. Do not "add" to innerHTML. Use DOM API e.g. `appendChild`

Comment: This answer is breaking so many things as @LukasLiesis has pointed. No idea why so many upvotes...

Comment: @Peska it has upvotes because it provides feel of working. You can run this code and it will do the thing. If app would have nothing more, it would be perfectly fine but usually apps have a bit more than such line, then stuff will break and it will be terrible day finding out why completely "unrelated" thing breaks your code. It's like AI generated code, often works w/o any clue of how wrong it is.

Answer (score 14):

Try the following syntax:

```
document.body.innerHTML += "<p>My new content</p>";
```

Comment: **For those coming to this question via Google etc:** This answers the question in the title. +1

Comment: Readers should also check out the excellent shortcut [in the answer by Ulysse BN](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45488487/1447509), below.

Comment: This does a replace + append, not just an append. On a long page, this could be very slow and one might see a page flash.

Comment: this brakes modern JS apps. use dom API `appendChild` or similar

Answer (score 6):

You're probably using

```
document.getElementById('element').innerHTML = "New content"
```

Try this instead:

```
document.getElementById('element').innerHTML += "New content"
```

Or, preferably, use [DOM](http://docs.webplatform.org/wiki/tutorials/traversing_the_dom) [Manipulation](http://docs.webplatform.org/wiki/tutorials/creating_and_modifying_html#Creating_HTML):

```
document.getElementById('element').appendChild(document.createElement("div"))
```

Dom manipulation would be preferred compared to using `innerHTML`, because `innerHTML` simply dumps a string into the document. The browser will have to reparse the entire document to get it's stucture.

Comment: Please don't suggest w3schools to people, it is not officially related to w3 and has a lot of misinformation (see http://w3fools.com )

Comment: @PaulS. If you have a different DOM manipulation tutorial for me, I'll gladly change the link.

Comment: I had to search for some and found these; [Navigating the DOM](http://docs.webplatform.org/wiki/tutorials/traversing_the_dom), [Modifying the DOM](http://docs.webplatform.org/wiki/tutorials/creating_and_modifying_html#Creating_HTML). True, they're not "easy reads" yet but it is a wiki in it's alpha stages.

Comment: @PaulS. Thanks, I'll add them in. I've just read through the page you linked... There's some pretty darn stupid mistakes around w3schools o.O

Comment: @Cerbrus man, there is no `innerHtml` property. Please, update your answer with the correct syntax - `innerHTML`.

Comment: @likerRr: It looks like you found a _very_ old answer of mine... Wow, I had much to learn back then o.O

Comment: So, @likerRr, care to remove the DV now?

Answer (score 3):

Working demo:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<title></title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
<script type="text/javascript">
onload = function(){
var divg = document.createElement("div");
divg.appendChild(document.createTextNode("New DIV"));
document.body.appendChild(divg);
};
</script>
</head>
<body>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

In most browsers, you can use a javascript variable instead of using `document.getElementById`. Say your html body content is like this:

```
<section id="mySection"> Hello </section>
```

Then you can just refer to `mySection` as a variable in javascript:

```
mySection.innerText += ', world'
// same as: document.getElementById('mySection').innerText += ', world'
```

See this snippet:

```js
mySection.innerText += ', world!'
```

```html
<section id="mySection"> Hello </section>
```

Answer (score 1):

you can also do like this

```
document.querySelector("#yourid").append('<div>my element<div>');
```

Answer (score 1):

```
document.querySelector('body').appendChild( //your content )
```

Answer (score 0):

Just:

```
    document.getElementById('myDiv').innerHTMl += "New Content";
```

Comment: hmm that will append then new html code not replace it

Comment: so I think the answer it's right but not explain at all

Answer (score 0):

recently, I faced the same issue but I wanted to add content just at the beginning of the content of the body. so I found this solution worthy:
using `insertAdjecentHTML(positions, text)` while specifying the position. The position can either `'beforebegin'`, `'afterbegin'`, `'beforeend'`, `'afterend'`

```
const element = document.getElementById('my-id')

element.insertAdjacentHTML(position, text);
```