# How to insert html to document using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net-web-api

I have a problem to insert html into document using javascript.

Code that trying to insert html into document:

```
function loadTaskPage(taskId){
    fetch("https://localhost:44321/api/Tasks/1")
    .then(function(response){
        return response.text();
    }).then(function(data){
        document.body.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', data);
    }).catch(function(error){
        alert(error);
    })
}
```

This code part I took from tutorial, source code of tutorial could be found in this link: https://github.com/bstavroulakis/progressive-web-apps/blob/master/car-deals/js/carService.js

If I will try to open this link `https://localhost:44321/api/Tasks/1` in browser I receive normally styled web page, but when I try to insert it to document, html code got escaped and don't display anything.

Inserted html looks like:

```
<div id="\"myModal\"" class="\"modal" fade\"="">...
```

The code below is bootstrap modal copied from code examples. As you see there appeared symbols `\"` that escapes quotes.

Response with html I receive from my ASP.Net Web Api with header: `text/html`

How should I insert this html code into document using javascript?

Comment: Similar to [How to add content to html body using javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13495010/how-to-add-content-to-html-body-using-javascript)

Comment: I have try to append `document.getElementById('main-content').innerHTML += data;` like this. But still there appears only text without any styles and still as I said in a ticket all class attributes are escaped.

Comment: It looks like the escaping in your html is off: there are too many `"`, your html string should be `"<div id=\"myModal\" class=\"modal" fade\">..."` otherwise the string inside `id` is `'"id"'` [see this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/u0Lzvq9p/)

Comment: note when I mentioned "the string inside `id`..." I meant that as an example, it's happening in more places than just the `id`

Comment: I have added a comment under answer, where I said that I have no idea why there appear additional quotes. my response string is: `<div id=\"myModal\" class=\"modal fade\">` like this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, looks like problem was in api service. In some reasons in debug mode showed to me correct html that I return to user. So after a few changes of api code all works as should.

If someone interested in ASP.Net Web API how to return view as a string and be able to add it to html all you need is to add Reference to `RazorEngine` and use the following code:

```
        var response = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK);
        var viewPath = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath(@"~/Views/Tasks/TaskDetails.cshtml");
        var template = File.ReadAllText(viewPath);

        var key = new NameOnlyTemplateKey("TaskDetails", ResolveType.Global, null);
        if(!Engine.Razor.IsTemplateCached(key, null))
            Engine.Razor.AddTemplate(key, new LoadedTemplateSource(template));

        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        StringWriter sw = new StringWriter(sb);
        Engine.Razor.RunCompile(key, sw, null, model);

        response.Content = new StringContent(sb.ToString());

        response.Content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("text/html");

        return response;
```

P.S. Code is not completely correct. It requires some optimizations.

Answer (score 3):

> How to insert html to document using javascript?

You can find that answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13495010/how-to-add-content-to-html-body-using-javascript):

> You can use
>
> ```
> document.getElementById("parentID").appendChild(/*..your content created using DOM methods..*/)
> ```
>
> or
>
> ```
> document.getElementById("parentID").innerHTML+= "new content"
> ```

As mentioned in the comments, this didn't seem to work and left the elements without style, this is because the escaping in the string being added to the `innerHTML` is off: there are too many `"`.

In the provided HTML example `<div id="\"myModal\"" class="\"modal" fade\"="">...` each attribute is surrounded by `"\" ... \""` which means that if you were to look at the string of the attribute's value it would look something like `'" ... "'`, which is what is causing the styles to not be added.

If you remove the extra `"` the HTML should be appended as expected:

```
<div id=\"myModal\" class=\"modal fade\">...
```

See this example showing what happens with the different escaping:

```js
document.getElementById("foo").innerHTML += '<div class="\"bar\"">Hello World!</div>'; // Escaped with too many `"`
document.getElementById("foo").innerHTML += '<div class=\"bar\">Hello World!</div>'; // Properly escaped
```

```css
.bar {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<div id="foo">

</div>
```

Comment: That the point, I didn't said that in ticket, in ASP.Net api I return response content like this: `<div id=\"myModal\" class=\"modal fade\">` and I don't understand why there appear more quotes...

Answer (score 1):

> The [insertAdjacentHTML()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/insertAdjacentHTML) method of the Element interface parses
>   the specified text as HTML or XML and inserts the resulting nodes into
>   the DOM tree at a specified position. It does not reparse the element
>   it is being used on, and thus it does not corrupt the existing
>   elements inside that element. This avoids the extra step of
>   serialization, making it much faster than direct innerHTML
>   manipulation.