# Populating HTML Table Data without Repetition

Tags: javascript, html

How can I populate multiple tables **without** copy and pasting code.
For instance loop through an array and assign

```
<p>AMD</p>
```

without copy and pasting the code below. Maybe looping and incrementing an id written in javascript. I just dont know how to go about it.

[image]

```
        <div class="chat-history">

            <div class="chat-message clearfix">

                <img src="http://lorempixum.com/32/32/people" alt="" width="32" height="32">

                <div class="chat-message-content clearfix"  onclick=alert("test")>

                    <span class="chat-time"></span>

                    <h5></h5>

                    <p>AMD</p>

                </div> <!-- end chat-message-content -->
```

I tried this im still working on it not fully understanding yet.

```
<div  class="chat">

        <div class="chat-history">

            <div class="chat-message clearfix">

                <img src="http://lorempixum.com/32/32/people" alt="" width="32" height="32">

                <div id="company" class="chat-message-content clearfix"  onclick=alert("hush")>

                    <span class="chat-time"></span>

                    <h5></h5>

                    <p >DCTH</p>

                </div> <!-- end chat-message-content -->

            </div> <!-- end chat-message -->

            <script>

                for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
                    document.getElementById("company").innerHTML+= "<p>TEST</p>"
                }



            </script>
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/13495046/2545197 this is what you need to do. use javascript to loop through it and insert new elements

Comment: where do I ad the parentID?

Comment: your items can go inside a `div`. something like `<div id="company"> </div>` and then through script you should insert your items in a `<p>` tag..something like: `document.getElementById("company").innerHTML+= "<p>AMD</p>"`. see if that works.

Comment: any thoughts on my update?

Answer (score 0):

your items can go inside a `div` and then through script you should insert your items in a `<p>` tag. added a sample script below:

```
        <div class="chat-history">

            <div class="chat-message clearfix">

                <img src="http://lorempixum.com/32/32/people" alt="" width="32" height="32">

                <div class="chat-message-content clearfix"  onclick=alert("hush")>

                    <span class="chat-time"></span>

                    <h5></h5>
                    <div id="company"></div>

                </div> <!-- end chat-message-content -->

            </div> <!-- end chat-message -->

            <script>
                var company = ["AMD", "APPLE"];
                company.forEach(function(i) {
                document.getElementById("company").innerHTML+= "<p>" + i + "</p>";
                });
            </script>
```

Comment: it populating them in the same cell

Comment: @husharoonie do you want this section (`class="chat-message-content"`) to be populated multiple times?

Comment: Where the div starts it creats another cell in my table as shown in the picture above. I want it to look exactly like the picture but without copy and paste

Comment: essentially putting a for loop around the entire code where the div starts and ends if that makes sense.

Comment: Yes what you need to figure out first is what are the common parts which needs no repetition. its just a matter of inserting dynamic parts using same code snippet.