# If element exists then add new div

Tags: jquery

I have been reading everywhere for a solution and I have tried all of them. But I am getting and error with this snippet:

```
if (jQuery('.page-id-5356 .uts-main-login')[0]){
  jQuery('.entry-content #em-wrapper').add('<div class="uts-login">text</div>');
}
```

Any ideas on why this isn't working? I either get nothing, a length of 2 or a geryed out `undefined`. No new div is created or anything. Basically, I want a a button to appear when on one page when `.uts-main-login` is visible. It's killing me! Been at it for hours :(

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Append div to end of document with jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6650963/append-div-to-end-of-document-with-jquery)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if(jQuery('.page-id-5356 .uts-main-login').is(":visible")) {
    jQuery('#em-wrapper').append('<div class="uts-login">text</div>');
}
```

1. You can use `is(':visible')` to check whether the element is visible or not.
2. If you have the id of the element no need to use class name before it.
3. Use `append()` to add the element

Answer (score 1):

Use like below

```
if (jQuery('.page-id-5356 .uts-main-login').length){
 jQuery('.entry-content #em-wrapper').append('<div class="uts-login">text</div>');
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `append`

```js
if (jQuery('.page-id-5356 .uts-main-login')[0]){
  jQuery('.entry-content #em-wrapper').append('<div class="uts-login">text</div>');
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='page-id-5356'>
<div class='uts-main-login'></div>
</div>
<div class='entry-content'>
<div id='em-wrapper'></div>
</div>
```